# PowerPoint: Fast text manipulation

Tags: vba, performance, powerpoint

**Setup:** I have a PowerPoint (16.0.4266.1001) presentation containing 8 identical slides. Each slide contains a lot of rectangles containing the text `1` (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nxjX.jpg). Each rectangle's boldness is randomly set (via a macro, if that matters: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/6qcVa1xj).

**Goal:** I would like to find the fastest to set all rectangles' boldness to specific values. To test things, I have two macros (`DoItSlow` and `DoItFast`) that set everything to bold, in two different ways.

`DoItSlow` traverses shape by shape and sets the boldness for each shape.

```
Sub DoItSlow()
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each shp In sld.Shapes
                shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
            Next shp
    Next sld
End Sub
```

`DoItFast` selects all shapes per slide, and applies boldness at once.

```
Sub DoItFast()
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
            sld.Shapes.Range.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    Next sld
End Sub
```

Both macros acchieve what I want, but `DoItFast` needs about 5 seconds, whereas `DoItSlow` needs about 20 seconds: So apparently batch-processing is *much* faster than doing it one by one. Could I acchieve the same speed while keeping the one-by-one approach?

**Background:** In the end, I do not want to set everything to bold, but decide on a per-rectangle-basis, and I'd prefer keeping work as local as possible without even touching the selection.

Comment: I am afraid it is not exactly possible. Iteration takes time...  Now, in the faster code, is the slide and shapes selection really necessary? It also consumes time and Application resources. I mean, did you try `shl.Shapes.TextRange2.Font.Bold = msoTrue`? Then, i suppose that you **must have a rule able to 'say'** which of them to be Bold and which not. I have in mind a scenario, but I cannot test it now, to prove that the next approach works: `shl.Shapes.Range(Array(1, 4, 10, 12)).TextRange2.Font.Bold = msoTrue`, as it does in Excel. So, does it work in your case (PowerPoint)?

Comment: If the answer is yes, based on the rule you want making the font bold in specific shapes/rectangles, **to build the necessary shapes array* and use is instead of `(Array(1, 4, 10, 12)`...

Comment: But, don't you need `Shapes.TextRange2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue` instead of `Shapes.TextRange2.Font.Bold = msoTrue`? I tested now in a slide and it accepts `Shapes.Range(Array())`, but only using the above construction...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks for your answers. Here my thoughts: (1) Iteration takes time: True, but it is surely not the bottleneck. Leaving out the call to `Font.Bold` from `DoItSlow` drastically increases speed, indicating that iteration is not a problem. (2) Slide and shape selection not necessary (please refer to updated question). (3) Your idea regarding the array is what I tried to frame in my question, but I explicitly would like to keep the one-by-one approach.

Comment: If iteration is not so problematic, the bolding itself if is done one by one, takes (much) more time then bolding (a range) **at once**. That's why I suggested to initially build the necessary `shapeRange` (shapes to be bolded array) and do the operation itself at once, for the obtained shapes array. I suppose you do  not want iterate for the sake of iteration. You must need to evaluate somehow some of the shapes properties/characteristics...

Comment: Please, try running the testing Subs I posted in my answer and send some feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Solution to increase to make the bolding code faster is to **firstly create an array of the shapes to be bolded** and do the bolding after that, **at once**, using the mentioned array.

Please, test the next two ways of bolding half of the shapes:

1. Bolding each of them per iteration:

```
Sub testBoldByIteration()
    Dim sl As Slide, shp As Shape, i As Long, t
    Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    sl.Shapes.Range.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoFalse
     t = Timer
    For Each shp In sl.Shapes
        i = i + 1
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    Next
    Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub
```

2. Placing the shapes to be bolded in an array and bold them at the end, **at once**:

```
Sub testBoldByArray()
    Dim sl As Slide, arrSh() As Long, i As Long, k As Long, t
    Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    sl.Shapes.Range.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoFalse
    ReDim arrSh(sl.Shapes.Count)
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To sl.Shapes.Count
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then arrSh(k) = i: k = k + 1
    Next
    ReDim Preserve arrSh(k - 1)
     sl.Shapes.Range(arrSh).TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
     Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub
```

The difference should be huge, for a big number of shapes...

Comment: You're right, the difference is huge, but I explicitly would like to acchieve the same performance using a one-by-one iteration. Of course, I do not iterate for the sake of iteration. Rather, my current code is doing many more things than just setting the boldness, and for all the other operations, it is much more convenient to be able to compute stuff on a one-by-one basis. Sorry if my question was not clear about this, but I do not have a problem collecting shapes and setting boldness once. Instead, I am looking for a way to avoid this altogether, as the remaining code relies on one-by-one.

Comment: @ But the above suggested solution **really treats the shapes one by one**! Do whatever you need with the shapes in discussion, but **instead of bolding the text of each specific ones, place their index in the array** and make the bolding at the end of the loop. In fact, **it is impossible to do what you ask as you put the problem**, since the speed difference is strictly connected **only to the discussed aspect**. Place any kind of condition to find the necessary ones! The `Mode` way was only place there to see the difference. **You have to replace it with your own algorithm**.

Comment: Maybe we have different definitions of one-by-one. To be a bit more concrete, in my case, the shapes are enumerated in a lot of (nested) sub-routines, and these sub-routines might e.g. even delete shapes. Thus, collecting shapes (across these subroutines) and doing the batch afterwards is not easily possible: It would clutter all the subroutines with collecting, and already collected shapes might have been deleted by another subroutine (might be problematic). Thus, I'd very much prefer a "real" one-by-one approach. Anyway, thanks for your effort, I'm upvoting your answer, as it might help.

Comment: @phimuemue I don't care too much about notoriety... What I'm trying to emphasize is the (unique) way to make your code faster... If you have to delete them, you **can also speed up this process in the same way**. Delete them at once, placing their index in another array! Then, **firstly apply the  bolding** and secondly deletion. No any problem related to shapes indexes... In order to easily work with subroutines, you should declare the array(s) variable on top the module, in the declarations area. If many modules involved, declare them `As Public`. This is what I would do being in your shoes.